# Force a view to refresh?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to do a loading icon where once you tap on the icon, it will call the following handler:

```
private void refresh_btn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
     refresh_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
     loading_icon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
     refreshMix();
}

private void refreshMix()
{
    ...
    refresh_btn.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    loading_icon.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

However, the view doesn't seem to auto-reload after I change the icon visibilities before calling refreshMix(). Is there a way to force the page to reload itself?

Comment: There should be no need to refresh the view, the button should automatically become collapsed once that line is hit. Sounds like the line isn't being reached. If you put a breakpoint inside the `refresh_btn_Tap` event, does it get hit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing some lengthy work in `refreshMix()` in UI thread, right? Do this work in background thread and UI thread will be free to update page.

Answer (score 1):

You need set Collapsed before Visible :

```
 control.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
 control.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

Within Silverlight there is no concept of page or view re-loading. When you change the properties of any visual element, this will be reflected on the screen the next time it is rendered.